# Display jQuery post data in a div

Tags: php, jquery, html

My alert does include the returned data and status.

My status is always "success" even when I throw an Exception which is another problem.

Here is my div:

```
<div id="login_error">*</div>
```

my jQuery code is:

```
$('#submit_login').click(function(){

        $userLogin = document.getElementById("user_login_name").value;
        $userPassword = document.getElementById("user_password").value;

            var returnedData = "";

            $.post("login_ldap.php", {
                userLogin: $userLogin,
                userPassword: $userPassword
            },

            function(data, status){
                alert("Data: " + data + '\nStatus: ' + status);
                returnedData = data;

                $('#login_error').append(returnedData);
                //document.getElementById("login_error").value = data;

            });


 });
```

UPDATE:
I added callback functions .done .fail & .always 
My alert statements work but my displaying to my div with id #login_error does not work

```
$.post("login_ldap.php", {userLogin: $userLogin, userPassword: $userPassword})

                    .done(function(data, status){
                        alert("Data: " + data + '\nStatus: ' + status);
                        $('#login_error').empty().append("done"); 
                        })
                    .fail(function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert("responseText " + xhr.responseText + "test Status " + textStatus + "errorThrown " + errorThrown);
                        // console.log("The following error occured: "+ textStatus, errorThrown);
                        $('#login_error').empty().append(xhr.responseText);
                        //$('#login_error').html(xhr.responseText);
                    })
                    .always(function() {
                        alert("finished");
                    });
```

I have tried appending a string instead of data and nothing displayed in my div.

my php code  is:

```
<?php
include_once 'classDB.php';

try {

  $userLogin = "";

  if (isset($_POST['userLogin'])) {
    $userLogin = $_POST['userLogin'];
   }
  else {
    echo "Enter Username";
    return -1;
  }

   $userPassword = "";

  if (isset($_POST['userPassword'])) {
    $userPassword = $_POST['userPassword'];   

  }
  else {
    echo "Enter Password";
    return -1;
  }
 echo  classDB::login_ldap($userLogin, $userPassword); 
}
catch ( Exception $e ) {
  echo "LOGIN ERROR: " . $e->getMessage();
  error_log($e->getMessage());
  exit(-1);

}

?>
```

This is my function:

```
public static function login_ldap($userLogin, $userPassword) {
   ... this is all working
  return "LOGIN SUCCESSFUL";
else
  throw new Exception("LOGIN FAILED:  binding error\nPlease try again.");
}
```

Comment: Your exception should include an http response code indicating a failure

Comment: I added this statement to my catchfunctionreturn(http_response_code(401));

Comment: Now I get a return code of failure. Thank you  I still can not display the data returned from .post to a div.  Any ideas?

Comment: Specify your callbacks `$.post(...).done(function(){//success)).fail(function(){//fail});` Or you can use `.always(function(){});`

Comment: I did just see my error message flash in my div but then it disappeared so my screen must be refreshing.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: not your main problem but you have jQuery in use. So instead of `document.getElementById("user_login_name").value` you can use `$('#user_login_name').val()`